# Custom shutdown start menu

Tags: c#, windows, chromebook

I've install Windows 10 on a Chromebook and actually there is an issue about the shutdown, when I shutdown from the startmenu the computer reboot instead of shutdown completely. So I've code a fix in C# and now I've an .exe who completely shutdown the computer, but I want to "link" this .exe to the shutdown button in the startmenu, is there a way to do that ?  (like change shutdown.exe in System32 ?) 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [this link](http://winaero.com/blog/set-the-shutdown-action-for-the-classic-shell-start-menu/) you should be able to change the default command the shutdown button is running. I don't think you can replace it with your .exe thought, maybe with an add-on?

But I think this link might resolve your problem!